# "Pantuflo" vs "pantufla": motivos del cambio y ejemplos similares

Tags: etimología, historia, sustantivos, ropa

En el idioma español contamos con la palabra *pantuflo* con casos en el CORDE desde el siglo XVI, con la siguiente definición:

> **[pantuflo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Rjqu23K)**
>
> Del fr. *pantoufle*.
>
> 1. m. Calzado, especie de chinela o zapato sin orejas ni talón, que para mayor comodidad se usa en casa.

Hoy en día se admite también la variante *[pantufla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RjqVdfd)*, con el mismo significado. Sin embargo, esta variante solo cuenta con entradas en el CORDE desde el siglo XIX mayormente, siglo en el cual ya este término aparecía en más ocasiones que *pantuflo*. Curiosamente, sí que hay 3 ocurrencias aisladas en el CORDE para *pantufla* en el siglo XVI (por 35 de *pantuflo*), pero no se vuelven a repetir hasta el siglo XIX, como dicho anteriormente. Es más, la RAE recoge *pantuflo* desde la primera versión del diccionario, mas no así *pantufla* que solo aparece desde 1884. Lo curioso es que a mí la versión femenina es la que me suena normal, y la masculina me suena muy rara.

Así pues, estudiemos este fenómeno:

- ¿Qué puede causar que una palabra cambie de género con el tiempo? En este caso concreto entiendo que pueda ser por influencia del francés, dado que en este idioma *pantoufle* es femenino. Es posible que inicialmente se adaptara fonéticamente como "pantuflo" y más tarde se adaptara el género al original francés. ¿Es así? ¿Hay casos que puedan tener una causa diferente?
- ¿Recibe algún nombre concreto este proceso del lenguaje?
- ¿Qué otras palabras conocemos que hayan sufrido este mismo fenómeno?

Comment: No tengo claro por dónde empezar a investigar pero creo que podría ser con pares existentes como bolsa-bolso, saco-saca, zapato-zapata, y otros del estilo caja-cajón, calle-callejón, zapato-zapatilla, donde el cambio de género sirve para crear nuevas palabras y el aumentativo/diminutivo no es literal.

Comment: @pablodf76 no tengo claro que sean los mismos ejemplos, porque los que mencionas hacen el cambio de género para designar conceptos nuevos, pero en el caso de "pantuflo-pantufla" designaba exactamente el mismo concepto.

Comment: Simple conjetura: asimilación de género de otras denominaciones para el calzado «de andar por casa»: las zapatillas, las chanclas, las alpargatas, las chancletas, las sandalias, las babuchas, etc. La única vez que lo he visto en masculino debe ser cuando leía las historietas de Zipi y Zape, porque su padre era Don Pantuflo Zapatilla.

Comment: Como nota curiosa: a veces se trata de diferencias regionales. En una zona de Colombia le llaman a una preparación del plátano "patacona" y yo la conozco como "patacón". En esa misma región usan la palabra "trapeadora" y yo he conocido la palabra como "trapeador".

Comment: Podrían llamarse _Sustantivos ambiguos en cuanto al género_ http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/G%C3%A9nero%20de%20los%20sustantivos.htm  [40 ejemplos de Substantivos Ambiguos](https://www.ejemplos.co/40-ejemplos-de-sustantivos-ambiguos/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En castellano hay varias palabras que en otras lenguas romances (mis referencias son gallego y francés) tienen diferente género. Son un quebradero de cabeza para los estudiantes hispanohablantes, os lo aseguro. Siempre he sospechado que ha sido en castellano donde cambiaron de género, así que he hecho algo de investigación con algunas de las palabras más comunes que tengo fichadas en este aspecto.

### Ejemplos

La información de los ejemplos que os propongo abajo ha sido consultada en el [Diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/dpd) (DPD), en el [Mapa de diccionarios académicos](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub) y el [Corpus de la RAE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) (CORDE).

- **Color**: En el mapa de diccionarios el género es consistentemente masculino, pero en el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=color) se dice que en el español antiguo y medieval era femenino. El CORDE recoge numerosos ejemplos de su empleo en femenino, desde la edad media hasta el S. XX.
- **Puente**: Según el mapa de diccionarios, ¡[ambiguo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg) hasta 1992! En el CORDE hay numerosísismos ejemplos de su uso en femenino, y en el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=puente) también se recoge que era femenino en español medieval antiguo. Particularmente curioso el caso de esta palabra, ya que en latín era masculino, luego cambió al femenino (de hecho, en gallego lo sigue siendo -*a ponte*-) y volvió al masculino en la época moderna.
- **Calor**: En el mapa de diccionarios el género es masculino desde el inicio, pero en las ediciones de 1992 y 2001 se empieza a citar el género femenino, como consecuencia de su uso popular. En el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=calor) se dice que en el español antiguo y medieval era femenino, y que en la lengua popular se sigue usando así, aunque en la lengua culta se prefiere el uso masculino.
- **Análisis**: Según el mapa de diccionarios, femenino en 1780 y 1817. [Ambiguo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg) en 1884 y 1925. Masculino a partir de 1992. En el DPD se aclara que el femenino no es correcto, un guiño a su origen femenino.
- **Fin**: Género consistentemente masculino en el mapa de diccionarios, pero en el CORDE encontramos referencias más antiguas que lo usan en femenino, hasta el S. XVII. De hecho, el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=fin) aclara que en el español antiguo era femenino pero a día de hoy debe usarse en masculino.

### Las causas

No sé a qué se debe este cambio en el género. Si os fijáis (¿quizás sea coincidencia?) son todo sustantivos que a día de hoy son masculinos. El vocablo original del latín en ocasiones era femenino (fin), y otras veces hay un doble cambio (puente, m→f→m).

En [*Aproximación a la historia de la lengua española → Del latín al romance español (pasando por el latín vulgar)*](http://users.jyu.fi/~torremor/cursos/hist-lengua/hist-lengua/05213.html) explican sucintamente la evolución de los géneros de las palabras del latín al español, aunque creo que no es aplicable a los casos que menciono. Además, no le dan un nombre al fenómeno, sino que más bien se le considera una **evolución natural del lenguaje**.

También se pueden pensar en otras causas como **influencias de otras lenguas**, o como se dice [aquí](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2017/07/27/articulo/1501160416_181007.html), por **analogía**: una palabra griega neutra terminada en *-a*, se pasó al masculino oficialmente, pero los hablantes acabarán pasándola al femenino por analogía.

### Nombre del fenómeno

En [*Masculinas, femeninas y viceversa: palabras con identidad transgénero*](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2017/07/27/articulo/1501160416_181007.html) citan otros ejemplos de palabras que cambian de género, algunos de ellos muy interesantes y curiosos, pero desafortunadamente para nosotros la autora no cita sus fuentes. En cambio, sí que da un nombre al fenómeno, bautizándolo como "**palabras transgénero**" :)